# Need to create custom shape for UIView Swift

Tags: swift, uikit

I need to create this custom UIView for my project.[I need to achieve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74tmz.png)

I was doing trial and error by creating, My own custom UIView and then drawing on it.
[I'm working on this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsPrm.png)

My Question is, if I'm able to draw my custom shape, How will I  clip-off the remaining white space of the UIView

```
    func drawCustomShape() {
    let viewSize = self.frame.size
    let buttonSlotRadius = CGFloat(30)
    let effectiveViewHeight = viewSize.height - buttonSlotRadius
    
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewSize.width - 30, y: 0))
    
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: viewSize.width - 30,
                                    y: 30),
                radius: 30,
                startAngle: .pi * 3 / 2,
                endAngle: 0,
                clockwise: true)
    
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewSize.width, y: effectiveViewHeight))
    
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: viewSize.width - 30,
                                    y: effectiveViewHeight - 30),
                radius: 30,
                startAngle: 0,
                endAngle: .pi / 2,
                clockwise: true)
    
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewSize.width / 4, y: effectiveViewHeight))
    
    // close path join to origin
    path.close()
    
    UIColor.secondarySystemFill.setFill()
    path.fill()
    
    path.lineWidth = 6.0
    path.stroke()
   
    
}
```

Comment: Maybe with [UIBezierPath](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-uibezierpath-and-cgpath-in-swiftui)?

Comment: [this](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/drawing-paths-and-shapes) could also be useful.

Comment: I have used UIBezierPath to create that rectangle, But Im not able to erase those white spaces.

Comment: Could you add the code that you used to draw that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UIView with **clear background color**, and use **CAShapeLayer** with desired path like this:

```
extension UIView {
    func drawCustomShape() {
        let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 18.0
        let shapeOffset = self.frame.size.height * 0.2

        //create shape layer
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        //create path
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        //top left point
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: cornerRadius))
        //top left corner
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: 0),
                          controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

        //top right point
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width - cornerRadius, y: 0))
        //top right corner
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: cornerRadius),
                          controlPoint: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: 0))

        //bottom right point
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height - shapeOffset - cornerRadius))
        //bottom right corner
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width - cornerRadius, y: self.frame.size.height - shapeOffset),
                          controlPoint: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height - shapeOffset))

        //bottom left
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: self.frame.size.height))
        //bottom left corner
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - cornerRadius),
                          controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height))

        path.close()

        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }
```

---

Usage:

```
myView.drawCustomShape()
```

---

Result:

[image: sample shape with 18 corner radius]